# Wordpress admin : customize filter in list view of custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type in WP using the register_post_type() function (following the examples provided in [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type))

It works fine but I would like to be able to filter posts in the admin panel when viewing the list. Right now I can only filter by date of publication, but I'd like to filter say, by author, or by the value of an arbitrary field (including custom).

Can this be achieved in `functions.php` when I register the custom post type?
Here's my code :

```
// A custom post type for 'film' items
function film_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Films',
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'film' ),
      'support' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'custom-fields' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'film', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'film_custom_init' );
```

Answer (score 2):

chaneg relationship to your fieldname you create in your advance custom field. repalce team post to your post typein hooks name and other locations, and put the whole code in your functions.php

```
add_filter('manage_edit-team_columns', 'custom_posts_table_head');
    function custom_posts_table_head( $columns ) {
        $columns['genre']  = 'Genre';
        return $columns;

    }
    add_action( 'manage_team_posts_custom_column', 'custom_posts_table_content', 10, 2);
    function custom_posts_table_content( $column_name,$post_id ) {
        if( $column_name == 'genre' ) {
            $post = get_field( 'relationship', $post_id );
            echo $post->post_title;
        }
    }

    add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'custom_post_author_wise_filter' );
        function custom_post_author_wise_filter(){
            if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'team' == $_GET['post_type']){
                wp_dropdown_posts( array(
                    'show_option_all' => __( 'Show All Genre', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                    'select_name' => 'genre_id',
                    'selected' => $_GET['genre_id']
                ));
            }
        }

        function parse_query_custom_post_author_wise_filter( $query ) {

            if( !is_admin() || $query->get( 'post_type' ) != 'team' )
                return $query;

            if (  isset($_GET['genre_id']) && $_GET['genre_id'] != '') {

            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'relationship'
                    ,'value' => $_GET['genre_id']
                    ,'compare' => '='
                ),
            ));
         }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','parse_query_custom_post_author_wise_filter');

        function wp_dropdown_posts( $args = '' ) {
            $defaults = array(
                'selected'              => FALSE,
                'pagination'            => FALSE,
                'posts_per_page'        => - 1,
                'post_status'           => 'publish',
                'cache_results'         => TRUE,
                'cache_post_meta_cache' => TRUE,
                'echo'                  => 1,
                'select_name'           => 'genre_id',
                'id'                    => '',
                'class'                 => '',
                'show'                  => 'post_title',
                'show_callback'         => NULL,
                'show_option_all'       => 'Select all Genre',
                'show_option_none'      => NULL,
                'option_none_value'     => '',
                'multi'                 => FALSE,
                'value_field'           => 'ID',
                'order'                 => 'ASC',
                'orderby'               => 'post_title',
            );
            $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

            $posts  = get_posts( array(
                'post_type'     => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'=> - 1,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    )
                );



            $output = '';
            $show = $r['show'];

            if( ! empty($posts) ) {

                $name = esc_attr( $r['select_name'] );
                if( $r['multi'] && ! $r['id'] ) {
                    $id = '';
                } else {
                    $id = $r['id'] ? " id='" . esc_attr( $r['id'] ) . "'" : " id='$name'";
                }

                $output = "<select name='{$name}'{$id} class='" . esc_attr( $r['class'] ) . "'>\n";
                if( $r['show_option_all'] ) {
                    $output .= "\t<option value='0'>{$r['show_option_all']}</option>\n";
                }
                if( $r['show_option_none'] ) {
                    $_selected = selected( $r['show_option_none'], $r['selected'], FALSE );
                    $output .= "\t<option value='" . esc_attr( $r['option_none_value'] ) . "'$_selected>{$r['show_option_none']}</option>\n";
                }
                foreach( (array) $posts as $post ) {
                    $value   = ! isset($r['value_field']) || ! isset($post->{$r['value_field']}) ? $post->ID : $post->{$r['value_field']};
                    $_selected = selected( $value, $r['selected'], FALSE );
                    $display = ! empty($post->$show) ? $post->$show : sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $post->ID );
                    if( $r['show_callback'] ) $display = call_user_func( $r['show_callback'], $display, $post->ID );
                    $output .= "\t<option value='{$value}'{$_selected}>" . esc_html( $display ) . "</option>\n";
                }
                $output .= "</select>";
            }
            $html = apply_filters( 'wp_dropdown_posts', $output, $r, $posts );
            if( $r['echo'] ) {
                echo $html;
            }
            return $html;
        }
```

Comment: repalce team post to your post type 'film'

Comment: Thanks. I'll need a little time to figure out how to make it work and I'll get back to you.

Comment: After the edits I proposed it seems to be working properly _except_ that the "show all" option doesn't work as expected (the list of films is empty). I supposed there's a problem in parse_query_custom_post_(etc) ? We're almost there...

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could do this for me. What happens in the query function isn't obvious to me.

Comment: please give me some details:
post type you are selecting, what is the name of custom field,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157548/discussion-between-guitarextended-and-rajkumar-gour).

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in functions.php of your theme. hope this will help

```
  add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'custom_post_author_wise_filter' );

    function custom_post_author_wise_filter(){
        if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'film' == $_GET['post_type']){
            wp_dropdown_users( array(
                'show_option_all' => __( 'Show All Authors', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                'name' => 'author_id',
                'selected' => $_GET['author_id']
            ));
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'parse_query', 'parse_query_custom_post_author_wise_filter' );

    function parse_query_custom_post_author_wise_filter( $query ){
        global $pagenow;
        if ( isset($_GET['post_type']) 
             && 'film' == $_GET['post_type'] 
             && is_admin() && 
             $pagenow == 'edit.php' 
             && isset($_GET['author_id']) 
             && $_GET['author_id'] != '') {
            $query->query_vars['author'] = $_GET['author_id'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works. How can I modify it to make it work with an custom field (say, "genre") ?

Comment: have you made the custom field with any plugin?

Comment: Yes, with Advanced Custom Fields. But I believe the fields are stored as regular custom fields in the database.

Comment: is the field saves single value (is it a text box or select ot multiple select)

Comment: It is a 'post object' field (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/)

Comment: of which post type. selection is multile or single

Comment: Single. It's a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: I have posted another answer for you.